# Printing a 2D array multiple times depending on user input

Tags: java, arrays, io, multidimensional-array

I posted about this assignment before, and I have the program pretty much working with the exception of one thing. The program asks the user what file they want to print, how many times they want to tile it across and how many times they want to tile it down. My program reads the file into a 2d array, and then it is supposed to tile it out. I am using three for loops to try to print it and it is printing the correct amount, however it is only printing vertically. I tried putting in a blank println to see if that would get it to print correctly but it is not working.  Anyone have any ideas? Here's the part of the code that stores the txt file into the 2d array and the method that is supposed to tile it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TileMap

{
    public static boolean yes;
    public static char response;
    public static int MAXSIDE = 100;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String fileName = "";
    public static int tilesAcross = 0;
    public static int tilesDown = 0;
    public static int imageHeight = 0;
    public static int imageWidth = 0;
    public static char userInput = 0;   
    static char [][] buffer = new char[MAXSIDE][MAXSIDE];
    static FileInputStream fstream = null;

public static void getImage()
{
    System.out.println("Getting Image...");

    try
    {   

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fstream = new Scanner(file);

        imageHeight = fstream.nextInt();
        imageWidth = fstream.nextInt();

        buffer = new char[imageHeight][imageWidth];
        int i = 0;

        while(fstream.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = fstream.nextLine();

                for(int l = 0; l < line.length(); l++)
                {
                    buffer[i][l] = line.charAt(l);
                }
            i++;
        }

        /*
        for(int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++)
        {
            String element = fstream.nextLine();
            for(int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++)
            {
                buffer[i][j] = element.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        */


        fstream.close();
    }


    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }


}




public static void doTileJob ()
    {

    for(int m = 0; m < tilesDown; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < tilesAcross;n++)
        {   
            for(int i= 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
                {
                    int w = 0;
                    System.out.print(buffer[i]);
                    System.out.println(buffer[w]);
                    w++;
                    }
            System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is imageHeight and imageWidth and why it is zero ?? I guess you are creating an array with size [0][0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use println() until you want to end the line (because there are no more tiles to the right of the current piece).

If you need to print two tiles next to each other, you need to print a line of the first tile, then the same line again until you have the right number of tiles wide before ending the line (with println).

For three tiles wide you would print the same line three times before ending the line.

Basically where I'm going is, switch the loop for the buffer with the loop for the tiles across. For each line in the buffer, repeat it for the number of tiles across, then end the line with a newline or use println("");